# NullPointerException on AlarmManager.setRepeating() - ElapsedRealTime - Android

Tags: android, sdk, nullpointerexception, background-service, elapsedtime

I am developing an android app, which turns the wifi on/off after every 5seconds (5seconds are just for testing)
If this information helps: I am using a NavigationDrawer for this app. I am using elapsedRealTime alarm for this. The user selects the time from a dropdown and after the selected time the app turns wifi on/off. For example: When he (the user) selects 30 minutes from the dropdown (spinner), the wifi should be turned on/off after 30minutes. I think that I have everything implemented (like `BroadcastReceiver`, `IntentService`).

My Code if it helps.
Here is how I call my `SpinnerTimeOnItemSelectedListener`class.

```
public class TweaksFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tweaks, container, false);
    addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
    return view;
}

public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection(){
    spinnerSelectTime = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_select_time);
    spinnerSelectTime.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SpinnerTimeOnItemSelectedListener());
}
```

In `SpinnerTimeOnItemSelectedListener` I am creating the alarm and executing the `BroadCastReceiver`after the alarm

```
   public class SpinnerTimeOnItemSelectedListener extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        if(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equals("Zeit auswählen") || parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equals("Select Time")){
            //onNothingSelected(parent);
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equals("30min")){
            alarm(parent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

    public void alarm(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        try {
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "alarm() is called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, BroadCastReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
            long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(); 
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                    firstTime, 10, mAlarmSender);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My `BroadCastReceiver` class

```
public class BroadCastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "BroadCastReceiver is running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    startWakefulService(context,new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class));
}
```

}

My `BackgroundService` class

```
public class BackgroundService extends IntentService {

public BackgroundService() {
    super("BackgroundService");
}
private WifiManager wifiManager;
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // Hier kommt der Code zum ein und ausschalten (von z.B. wifi)
    // Ein Intentservice gibt nichts auf der UI aus
    wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
    } else {
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
    }
}
}
```

My Manifest file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.selfmade.ali.wifionoffer" >
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SpinnerTimeOnItemSelectedListener" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".ElapsedRealtimeAlarm"></activity>

    <receiver android:name=".BroadCastReceiver" ></receiver>
    <service android:name=".BackgroundService" android:exported="false" android:enabled="true" ></service>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

I am becoming a NullPointerException on this line: `am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, firstTime, 10000, mAlarmSender);` What can be the issue and how can I solve it?
Here is the logcat if it helps:

```
07-27 15:24:29.490  20446-20446/com.selfmade.ali.wifionoffer W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
07-27 15:24:29.500  20446-20446/com.selfmade.ali.wifionoffer W/System.err﹕ at com.selfmade.ali.wifionoffer.SpinnerTimeOnItemSelectedListener.alarm(SpinnerTimeOnItemSelectedListener.java:93)
07-27 15:24:29.500  20446-20446/com.selfmade.ali.wifionoffer W/System.err﹕ at com.selfmade.ali.wifionoffer.SpinnerTimeOnItemSelectedListener.onItemSelected(SpinnerTimeOnItemSelectedListener.java:38)
07-27 15:24:29.500  20446-20446/com.selfmade.ali.wifionoffer W/System.err﹕ at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:956)
07-27 15:24:29.500  20446-20446/com.selfmade.ali.wifionoffer W/System.err﹕ at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:49)
07-27 15:24:29.500  20446-20446/com.selfmade.ali.wifionoffer W/System.err﹕ at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:920)
07-27 15:24:29.500  20446-20446/com.selfmade.ali.wifionoffer W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-27 15:24:29.500  20446-20446/com.selfmade.ali.wifionoffer W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-27 15:24:29.500  20446-20446/com.selfmade.ali.wifionoffer W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
07-27 15:24:29.500  20446-20446/com.selfmade.ali.wifionoffer W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
07-27 15:24:29.500  20446-20446/com.selfmade.ali.wifionoffer W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-27 15:24:29.500  20446-20446/com.selfmade.ali.wifionoffer W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-27 15:24:29.500  20446-20446/com.selfmade.ali.wifionoffer W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
07-27 15:24:29.500  20446-20446/com.selfmade.ali.wifionoffer W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
07-27 15:24:29.500  20446-20446/com.selfmade.ali.wifionoffer W/System.err﹕ at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
07-27 15:24:29.500  20446-20446/com.selfmade.ali.wifionoffer W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-27 15:24:51.692  20446-20446/com.selfmade.ali.wifionoffer W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
07-27 15:24:51.692  20446-20446/com.selfmade.ali.wifionoffer W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-27 15:24:51.702  20446-20446/com.selfmade.ali.wifionoffer W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
07-27 15:24:51.702  20446-20446/com.selfmade.ali.wifionoffer W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
```

I am having this issue for 3 days and I hope that somebody can help me

Comment: `SpinnerTimeOnItemSelectedListener` should _not_ be a subclass of `Activity`.

Comment: Please see http://sscce.org/ on help to pinpoint your problem so others can help you easier.

Comment: @MikeM. when I delete the Activity I become more errors. For example on this line `am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);` with this error: `cannot resolve methot getSystemService(?)`

Comment: Make `SpinnerTimeOnItemSelectedListener` an inner class of the Activity or Fragment that contains the Spinner. Move the `alarm()` method to the Activity/Fragment, and get rid of the `AdapterView` parameter. If it's in an Activity, it'll work as is. If it's a Fragment, use `getActivity().getSystemService()`. Also remove the `SpinnerTimeOnItemSelectedListener` entry from the manifest.

Comment: I removed the `onCreate` and moved the code `am = ...` to `alarm()` and used `am = (AlarmManager) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);` and know it is working. thanks. but there is still an issue: Now there is no exception or error. After the 10seconds, he isn't executing my pendingIntent, because in my `BroadCastReceiver`class I have a Toast at the beginning (the code is above). what can be the issue and how to solve it?

Comment: @MikeM. and again you helped me solving my problem. Thank you